# searching friends using facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does facebook have an api for searching a user's friend?

Tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the list of friends using the following API call:

```
Friends: https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=...
```

and then search in the list for the person you are looking for.

Refer to more detailed documentation here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

Comment: can I apply filter in this API .. means I want search "AMIT" within my friends only. .  .  .  .
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Amit&type=user this API search user AMIT but it search publicly but I want to search within friend list only

Comment: Agree with @AmitBattan, I didn't found anything in the Facebook docs to do that, which is weird. Well done Facebook, well done...

Answer (score 6):

You can search friend's name like this:

```
select uid, name, sex 
from user 
where uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
and (strpos(lower(name),'TheFriendName')>=0 OR strpos(name,'TheFriendName')>=0)
```

**TheFriendName**=Full name or part of the name

Example:

```
select uid, name, sex 
from user 
where uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
and (strpos(lower(name),'Jack')>=0 OR strpos(name,'Jack')>=0)
```

Comment: *sidenote:* FQL will soon be deprecated. Read [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) for more details.