# Graph API: how to search for friends using a keyword

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, search

I need to provide a search option for my friends. If I use "me/friends", it will list all my friends. If I use "search?q=keyword", I will get search results, which contains non friends.

Is their a way to search FB users, who are my friend?

Comment: possible duplicate of [searching friends using facebook graph api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466953/searching-friends-using-facebook-graph-api)

Comment: This does not help. I have already mentioned this is in the question. Because friends list might contain more than thousand entries. So we have to paginate the friends-list. So user should be given an option search through the friend list alone.

Answer (score 5):

Probably the easiest way is via FQL using code something like this:

```
SELECT name, about_me FROM user WHERE 
   uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
   AND 
     (
        strpos(lower(name), lower([SEARCH])) >= 0 
        OR 
        strpos(lower(about_me), lower([SEARCH])) >= 0
      )
```

Comment: I need to use Graph API, any way to achieve that using Graph API ? Anyway thanks for the info. :)

Comment: The iOS SDK has an FQL endpoint. If you're not comfortable with that, you can pass it to the API as `/fql?q=[URL_ENCODED_FQL_QUERY]`