# Facebook graph api search friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way using the graph api to search all users but to list matching friends first?

If I search using [this](https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=SEARCHNAME&type=user) it requires a user access_token. So it knows who I am. So why does it (almost seem like its) avoiding displaying my friends? Why doesn't it return my friends that match the query first and then after that, anyone else?

Is there a way to make it mimic that functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also wondered the same thing as the OP.  The only thing I've been able to come up with in my research is using FQL...The problem with FQL?  After v 2.0 of the Facebook API it will no longer be available--and the version after that it will probably be deprecated.

But in the interest of getting a working solution NOW, I found this SO (third answer down):  [searching friends using facebook graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466953/searching-friends-using-facebook-graph-api)

Here's the example that worked for me:

```
select uid, name, sex 
from user 
where uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
and (strpos(lower(name),'Jack')>=0 OR strpos(name,'Jack')>=0)
```

Also, if you want their pic use:

```
select uid, name, sex, pic_small 
from user 
where uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
and (strpos(lower(name),'Jack')>=0 OR strpos(name,'Jack')>=0)
```

(I'm getting their small pic but documentation for other sizes of the pic is found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/)

Comment: I also should state explicitly that this will still only get friends that have your app installed...since 2.0 this was a limitation put on the platform in order to respect other user's privacy.  There is a bit of a revolt over this limitation that you can read more about via a bug filed at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1502515636638396/.  The only way to get ALL friends is via the "taggable_friends" or "invitable_friends" graph end points.  And even then Facebook has to review and approve it's usage for your app if you want to use it in production.